# Is there a meta-language that can sit-over a Selenium test suite?

Tags: selenium

We have many thousands of test scenarios we would like to test for in a web application.
Is there a meta-language system that a non-programmer could use to specify the tests to be performed and results obtained?
For example:

Check for button:"Commit"

Press button "Commit"

Check for no button "Commit"

Check for Text Box:"box_error","No data entered"

Comment: Selenium IDE is a Firefox plugin that lets you record actions interactively and export recorded macros to various programming languages.
http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

Comment: Thank you for your help. We have researched this, tried it and decided it was not appropriate in this particular case. The problem we felt was that changes in the future would require a software change rather than just an edit to the meta language input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Behat](http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/) BDD which uses [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin) language. We have a QA people who have zero knowledge about programming and they write all those scenarios for us(developers) so anyone can write one scenario and understand it. It can be in any language. It is widely used.

For example:

```
Feature: User can search something in Google
  As a user
  I want to be able search something in Google

  Scenario: I'll search Behat in Google
    Given I am on "http://www.google.com/"
    When I fill in "search_box" with "Behat"
    And I press "Search"
    Then I should see "Behat Documentation"
```

The result can either be seen in command line or in an actual brower window like Firefox, Chrome, Opera .... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHPgFvkk4Mo

There are many [already defined lines/steps](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-behat-extension#cheatsheet) for you to use. If there is something missing then you can easily create one with its expected behavior. Checkout this [cheat sheet](http://blog.lepine.pro/images/2012-03-behat-cheat-sheet-en.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for this. We had researched Selenium and we use HP's UTF and this does seem like a unifying technology.

Comment: Good luck with it. It very easy and simple to use and understand. I learned in 1 week. We tell non-programmers how to write those scenarios/steps once and they don't come back to ask anything. Then programmers do the rest which is also simple for them.

Answer (score 1):

Robot framework (http://www.robotframework.org) is one such tool. It is a keyword driven acceptance testing framework from which you can drive a browser with selenium. Your test could, for example, look literally like what you ask for.

It's not a tool you can just drop in and let your non-programmers use. There are many built-in keywords, and additional third-party libraries, but to get a set of keywords for your specific problem domain would require a little work.

Comment: Thanks you for taking the time to help and the quick response. We will investigate this option. It does look close to what we had hoped for.